# State in bloc is not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

Im learning flutter and bloc and I build simple app in flutter. Math quiz on time. I have a model with math operation.
When I press event get numbers i get calcState with random numbers so it works fine all times but when i want press answer my calcState is not updating but on terminal my model result it's changing.

This is my bloc

```
class CalcBloc extends Bloc<CalcEvent, CalcState> {
  CalcBloc() : super(const CalcInitial()) {
    on<CalcResult>(_onGetNumbers);
    on<NumberPressed>(_onNumberPressed);
  }

  Random random = Random();
  var list = ['+', '-'];
  bool check = false;

  void _onGetNumbers(CalcResult event, Emitter<CalcState> emit) {
    int randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(100);
    int randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(100);
    var element = list[random.nextInt(list.length)];
    bool check = true;
    if (check) {
      print('true');
    }
    CalcModel model = state.calcModel.copyWith(
        firstOperand: randomNumber1,
        firstOperator: element,
        secondOperand: randomNumber2,
        result: null);
    emit(CalcState(calcModel: model));
    print(model);
  }

  void _onNumberPressed(NumberPressed event, Emitter<CalcState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    CalcModel model = state.calcModel.copyWith(
        firstOperand: state.calcModel.firstOperand,
        firstOperator: state.calcModel.firstOperator,
        secondOperand: state.calcModel.secondOperand,
        result: event.number);
    emit(CalcState(calcModel: model));
    print(model);
  }
}
```

This is my State

```
class CalcState extends Equatable {
  final CalcModel calcModel;
  const CalcState({this.calcModel = const CalcModel()});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [calcModel];
}

class CalcInitial extends CalcState {
  const CalcInitial() : super(calcModel: const CalcModel());
}
```

Event

```
abstract class CalcEvent extends Equatable {
  const CalcEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CalcResult extends CalcEvent {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class NumberPressed extends CalcEvent {
  final int number;

  const NumberPressed({required this.number});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [number];
}
```

And Screen

```
class TestingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestingScreen> createState() => _TestingScreenState();
}

class _TestingScreenState extends State<TestingScreen> {
  @override

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<CalcBloc, CalcState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              Center(child: state.calcModel.firstOperand == null ? const Text('') : Text(state.calcModel.toString())),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80, vertical: 40),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _numberbutton(text: '7', onTap: () => numberPressed(7)),
                    _numberbutton(text: '8', onTap: () => numberPressed(8)),
                    _numberbutton(text: '9', onTap: () => numberPressed(9)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80, vertical: 40),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _numberbutton(text: '4', onTap: () => numberPressed(4)),
                    _numberbutton(text: '5', onTap: () => numberPressed(5)),
                    _numberbutton(text: '6', onTap: () => numberPressed(6)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80, vertical: 40),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _numberbutton(text: '1', onTap: () => numberPressed(1)),
                    _numberbutton(text: '2', onTap: () => numberPressed(2)),
                    _numberbutton(text: '3', onTap: () => numberPressed(3)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 80, vertical: 40),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    _numberbutton(text: '0', onTap: () => numberPressed(0)),
                    _numberbutton(
                        text: '=',
                        onTap: () {
                          context.read<CalcBloc>().add(CalcResult());
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _numberbutton({
    required String text,
    required VoidCallback onTap,
  }) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

  void numberPressed(int number) {
    context.read<CalcBloc>().add(NumberPressed(number: number));
  }
}
```

I have

- flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1,
- bloc: ^8.0.3,
- equatable: ^2.0.3

There is CalcModel

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class CalcModel extends Equatable {
  final int? firstOperand;
  final String? firstOperator;
  final int? secondOperand;
  final String? secondOperator;
  final int? thirdOperand;
  final String? thirdOperator;
  final int? fourthOperand;
  final int? result;
  const CalcModel(
      {this.firstOperand,
      this.firstOperator,
      this.secondOperand,
      this.secondOperator,
      this.thirdOperand,
      this.thirdOperator,
      this.fourthOperand,
      this.result});

  CalcModel copyWith({
    int? firstOperand,
    String? firstOperator,
    int? secondOperand,
    String? secondOperator,
    int? thirdOperand,
    String? thirdOperator,
    int? fourthOperand,
    int? result,
  }) {
    return CalcModel(
        firstOperand: firstOperand ?? this.firstOperand,
        firstOperator: firstOperator ?? this.firstOperator,
        secondOperand: secondOperand ?? this.secondOperand,
        secondOperator: secondOperator ?? this.secondOperator,
        thirdOperand: thirdOperand ?? this.thirdOperand,
        thirdOperator: thirdOperator ?? this.thirdOperator,
        fourthOperand: fourthOperand ?? this.fourthOperand,
        result: result ?? this.result);
  }

  CalcModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : firstOperand = json['firstOperand'] as int?,
        firstOperator = json['firstOperator'] as String?,
        secondOperand = json['secondOperand'] as int?,
        secondOperator = json['secondOperator'] as String?,
        thirdOperand = json['thirdOperand'] as int?,
        thirdOperator = json['thirdOperator'] as String?,
        fourthOperand = json['fourthOperand'] as int?,
        result = json['result'] as int?;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'firstOperand': firstOperand,
        'firstOperator': firstOperator,
        'secondOperand': secondOperand,
        'secondOperator': secondOperator,
        'thirdOperand': thirdOperand,
        'thirdOperator': thirdOperator,
        'fourthOperand': fourthOperand,
        'result': result,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$firstOperand $firstOperator $secondOperand = $result';
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        firstOperand,
        firstOperator,
        secondOperand,
        secondOperator,
        thirdOperand,
        thirdOperator,
        fourthOperand
      ];
}
```

Comment: Can you include the `CalcMolder` class

Comment: You mean source code here?

Comment: Yes just  the model class `CalcModel`

Comment: Ok I implement this

Answer (score 0):

If you check this, we aren't changing anything to trigger to update the state. We Are creating the same data model (equitable variables), there is no changes from current state and result is no update on UI.

```dart
void _onNumberPressed(NumberPressed event, Emitter<CalcState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    CalcModel model = state.calcModel.copyWith(
        firstOperand: state.calcModel.firstOperand,
        firstOperator: state.calcModel.firstOperator,
        secondOperand: state.calcModel.secondOperand,
        result: event.number);
    emit(CalcState(calcModel: model));
    print(model);
  }
```

We have `NumberPressed` event that provide tapped number.

We can do like, I am not doing perfect operation, just to show the UI update cases

And for the `CalcResult` it is passing null on result.

```dart
class CalcBloc extends Bloc<CalcEvent, CalcState> {
  CalcBloc() : super(const CalcInitial()) {
    on<CalcResult>(_onGetNumbers);
    on<NumberPressed>(_onNumberPressed);
  }

  Random random = Random();
  var list = ['+', '-'];
  bool check = false;

  void _onGetNumbers(CalcResult event, Emitter<CalcState> emit) {
    int randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(100);
    int randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(100);
    var element = list[random.nextInt(list.length)];
    bool check = true;
    if (check) {
      print('true');
    }

    final result = state.calcModel.firstOperator == list.first
        ? randomNumber1 + randomNumber2
        : randomNumber1 - randomNumber2;
    CalcModel model = state.calcModel.copyWith(
        firstOperand: randomNumber1,
        firstOperator: element,
        secondOperand: randomNumber2,
        result: result);
    emit(CalcState(calcModel: model));
    print(model);
  }

  void _onNumberPressed(NumberPressed event, Emitter<CalcState> emit) {
    final state = this.state;
    CalcModel model = state.calcModel.copyWith(
      firstOperand: state.calcModel.firstOperand ?? event.number,
      firstOperator: list.first,
      secondOperand: state.calcModel.firstOperand != null ? event.number : null,
      result: (state.calcModel.firstOperand ?? 0) +
          (state.calcModel.secondOperand ?? 0),
    );
    emit(CalcState(calcModel: model));
  }
}
```

There are also tiny clickable area for inkWell, you reduce margin and padding and can check more about
[ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/tutorial)

Check more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and [bloclibrary](https://bloclibrary.dev/)